# differentiation of a norm of matrix function

Tags: matrices, derivatives, inverse, matrix-equations

I need to differentiate the following function W.r.to $x$ 
$y=\|x (\mathbf{I-W}-x \mathbf{Diag(v_2)W})^{-1}\mathbf{v_1} - b\|_2$
where $0<x<\frac{2}{max_i{|{v_2}_i|}}$,$\mathbf{v_1}\in \mathscr{R}^n,\mathbf{v_2}\in [\mathscr{R}^n]^-$ are  vectors,$\mathbf{I}$ is identity matrix, $\mathbf{W}$ is a doubly stochastic matrix. And $b = -\frac{\sum{{v_1}_i}}{\sum{{v_2}_i}}$ , is the limit point of $x(\mathbf{I-W}-x \mathbf{Diag(v_2)W})^{-1}\mathbf{v_1}$ as $x\to 0$. I had seen by simulation that $y$ is strictly increasing in the given range of $x$ as x goes from $0$ to max.

Comment: which norm ? the $\|.\|_2$ ?

Comment: yes, it's 2 norm

Comment: hence you should write $\|u\|^2 = u^T u$, and use that if $\epsilon$ is small enough $(I - \epsilon A)^{-1} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \epsilon^k A^k$

Comment: Here i get $(I-\mathbf{DW})^{-1}$ and $ \|\mathbf{DW\|}<1 $, where $\mathbf{D} =  (I-x\mathbf{Diag(v_2)})$. The expansion will be of the form $I+\sum_i \mathbf(DW)^i$. I am unable to further simplify the notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a few variables for convenience
$$\eqalign{
 v &= v_1 \cr
 D &= {\rm Diag}(v_2) \cr
 E &= I-W-DWx \cr
dE &= -DW\,dx \cr\cr
 h &= E^{-1}vx-b \cr
dh &= E^{-1}v\,dx - E^{-1}\,dE\,E^{-1}vx \cr
   &= E^{-1}v\,dx - E^{-1}(-DW)E^{-1}vx\,dx \cr
   &= (E^{-1} + xE^{-1}DWE^{-1})\,v\,\,dx \cr\cr
}$$
Now write the objective function and find its differential
$$\eqalign{
 y &= h^Th \cr
dy &= 2h^Tdh \cr
   &= 2h^T(E^{-1} + xE^{-1}DWE^{-1})\,v\,dx \cr\cr
}$$
From that last expression, the derivative wrt $x$ must be
$$\eqalign{
\frac{dy}{dx} &= 2h^T(E^{-1} + xE^{-1}DWE^{-1})\,v \cr
}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer Lynn. It would have been very helpful if I could show that $\frac{dy}{dx}\geq 0$ i.e $y$ is an increasing function of x. Unfortunately it cannot be deduced from this.